# How to add model events to an event subscriber class in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, events, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I would like to refactor some event so I've created an event subscriber class.

```
class UserEventListener
{
    public function onUserLogin($event, $remember) {

        $event->user->last_login_at = Carbon::now();

        $event->user->save();
    }

    public function onUserCreating($event) {
         $event->user->token = str_random(30);
    }

    public function subscribe($events)
    {
      $events->listen(
        'auth.login',
        'App\Listeners\UserEventListener@onUserLogin'
       );

      $events->listen(
        'user.creating',
        'App\Listeners\UserEventListener@onUserCreating'
       );
    }
}
```

I register the listener as follows:

```
 protected $subscribe = [
    'App\Listeners\UserEventListener',
];
```

I added the following to the boot method of the user model as follows:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::creating(function ($user) {
       Event::fire('user.creating', $user);
    });
}
```

But when I try the login I get following error:

`Indirect modification of overloaded property App\User::$user has no effect`

Whats wrong with the `onUserLogin` signature? I thought you can access user using $event->user...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use event subscribers, you'll need to listen on the events that Eloquent models fire at different stages of their lifecycle.

If you have a look at **fireModelEvent** method of Eloquent model, you'll see that the event names that are fired are built the following way:

```
$event = "eloquent.{$event}: ".get_class($this);
```

where **$this** is the model object and **$event** is the event name (creating, created, saving, saved, etc.). This event is fired with a single argument, being the model object.

Another option would be to use **model observers** - I prefer that to event subscribers as it makes listening on different lifecycle events easier - you can find an example here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#model-observers

Regarding **auth.login**, when this event is fired, 2 parameters are passed along - **user** that logged in and the **remember flag**. Therefore, you'll need to define a listener that takes 2 arguments - first will be the user, second will be the remember flag.

Comment: This is a question about laravel 5.1. I think model observers are more to do with laravel 5.

Comment: They are still there in 5.1 and have not been deprecated. But as I said, that is just one of the options, feel free to use event subscribers if you prefer.